# Javascript jquery json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

OK, so I have a json structure as follows.

Basically, what I want to do is loop over the json file and pull out the data if Country is equal to a specific value.

I'm sure this is pretty easy but i just can't work it out.

```
    {
"Site ID": 19955,
"Hotels": "Ramada Salzburg City Centre",
"Stadt": "Salzburg",
"Country": "Austria",
"Region": "Central & Eastern Europe",
"Link DE": "",
"Link EN": "",
"Link TR": "",
"Lat": 47.8137521,
"Long": 13.044259,
"Image": "/Salzburg.jpg"
     }
```

Comment: Post your attempt.

Comment: "pull out the data" - please explain this phrase, it's nonsensical

Comment: sorry, append the data to a li tag for ecxample

Comment: Already answered there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40711728/jquery-loop-through-json-objects/40716131#40716131

Answer (score 2):

Use `Array.prototype.filter`

```
let austrianSites = sites.filter(site => site.Country === 'Austria')
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
for (var i = 0, len = structure.length; i < len; i++) {
  if (structure[i].Country === someValue) {
    // do something here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about checking if the JSON object has a property "Country" and if it does then output it. Hope it helps!

```js
var jsonObject =  {
"Site ID": 19955,
"Hotels": "Ramada Salzburg City Centre",
"Stadt": "Salzburg",
"Country": "Austria",
"Region": "Central & Eastern Europe",
"Link DE": "",
"Link EN": "",
"Link TR": "",
"Lat": 47.8137521,
"Long": 13.044259,
"Image": "wp-content/themes/wyndham-hotels/img/Salzburg.jpg"
     }

for(var i in jsonObject){
  if(jsonObject.hasOwnProperty("Country")){
    var x = jsonObject.Country;
  }
}
document.write("The Country is: " + x);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this following:

```js
var places = [{
  "Site ID": 19955,
  "Hotels": "Ramada Salzburg City Centre",
  "Stadt": "Salzburg",
  "Country": "Austria",
  "Region": "Central & Eastern Europe",
  "Link DE": "",
  "Link EN": "",
  "Link TR": "",
  "Lat": 47.8137521,
  "Long": 13.044259,
  "Image": "/Salzburg.jpg"
}, {
  "Site ID": 1211,
  "Hotels": "test",
  "Stadt": "Salzburg",
  "Country": "NZ",
  "Region": "Central & Eastern Europe",
  "Link DE": "",
  "Link EN": "",
  "Link TR": "",
  "Lat": 47.8137521,
  "Long": 13.044259,
  "Image": "/Salzburg.jpg"
}]

var filtered = places.filter(function(p) {
  return p.Country === "NZ";
})
console.log(filtered);
```