# jQuery loop through JSON objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to loop through this JSON file (structure below) and get all Hotels where country is Austria for example. Using `getJson()` so am unable to change anything in the JSON file too.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
[
  {
    "Site ID": 19955,
    "Hotels": "Ramada Salzburg City Centre",
    "Stadt": "Salzburg",
    "Country": "Austria",
    "Region": "Central & Eastern Europe",
    "Link DE": "",
    "Link EN": "",
    "Link TR": "",
    "Lat": 47.8137521,
    "Long": 13.044259,
    "Image": "/Salzburg.jpg"
  }, {
    "Site ID": 1211,
    "Hotels": "test",
    "Stadt": "Salzburg",
    "Country": "NZ",
    "Region": "Central & Eastern Europe",
    "Link DE": "",
    "Link EN": "",
    "Link TR": "",
    "Lat": 47.8137521,
    "Long": 13.044259,
    "Image": "/Salzburg.jpg"
  }
]
```

Comment: What code do you have so far

Comment: you can use forEach

Comment: var json = "URL";

$.getJSON(json, function (json) {

    for(var i in json){
  if(json.hasOwnProperty("Country")){
    var x = json.Country.Hotels;
  }
}
document.write(x);

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what exactly you want to do, but here's a working example that loops the json and checks if the hotel is in Austria and logs the name and city into the console:

```
var json = [{
  "Site ID": 19955,
  "Hotels": "Ramada Salzburg City Centre",
  "Stadt": "Salzburg",
  "Country": "Austria",
  "Region": "Central & Eastern Europe",
  "Link DE": "",
  "Link EN": "",
  "Link TR": "",
  "Lat": 47.8137521,
  "Long": 13.044259,
  "Image": "/Salzburg.jpg"
}, {
  "Site ID": 1211,
  "Hotels": "test",
  "Stadt": "Salzburg",
  "Country": "NZ",
  "Region": "Central & Eastern Europe",
  "Link DE": "",
  "Link EN": "",
  "Link TR": "",
  "Lat": 47.8137521,
  "Long": 13.044259,
  "Image": "/Salzburg.jpg"
}];

$(json).each(function () {
  if (this.Country === "Austria") {
    console.log("Found hotel " + this.Hotels + " in " + this.Stadt);
  }
});
```

Comment: Why use "==" instead of "==="?  Put a temp down vote for that but will reverse it after edit.

Comment: YES! Thank you i had to inject external json file as variable but it worked.

Comment: Indeed, in this case there is no preference of the equality over the identity operator, I edited the source to use the "good" one :P

Comment: thanks.  flipped my down vote to an up vote.  Agreed that in this case it wouldn't make a difference since there is no implicit type conversion since it is string to string.  Just want good examples for the programmers just starting out.

Comment: I'm totally with you. Stackoverflow is the go-to source for any solution, so we should strive to provide the best examples possible.

Answer (score 0):

**Try Array [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method :**

```js
var json = [{
  "Site ID": 19955,
  "Hotels": "Ramada Salzburg City Centre",
  "Stadt": "Salzburg",
  "Country": "Austria",
  "Region": "Central & Eastern Europe",
  "Link DE": "",
  "Link EN": "",
  "Link TR": "",
  "Lat": 47.8137521,
  "Long": 13.044259,
  "Image": "/Salzburg.jpg"
}, {
  "Site ID": 1211,
  "Hotels": "test",
  "Stadt": "Salzburg",
  "Country": "NZ",
  "Region": "Central & Eastern Europe",
  "Link DE": "",
  "Link EN": "",
  "Link TR": "",
  "Lat": 47.8137521,
  "Long": 13.044259,
  "Image": "/Salzburg.jpg"
}];

var austriaHotels = json.filter(function(item) {
  return item.Country == 'Austria';
});

var hotelsName = austriaHotels.map(function(item) {
  return item.Hotels;
});

console.log(hotelsName);
```

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to store your locations, loop over them and group together the matching locations into a new array.

```
var locations = [{
  "Site ID": 19955,
  "Hotels": "Ramada Salzburg City Centre",
  "Stadt": "Salzburg",
  "Country": "Austria",
  "Region": "Central & Eastern Europe",
  "Link DE": "",
  "Link EN": "",
  "Link TR": "",
  "Lat": 47.8137521,
  "Long": 13.044259,
  "Image": "/Salzburg.jpg"
}, {
  "Site ID": 1211,
  "Hotels": "test",
  "Stadt": "Salzburg",
  "Country": "NZ",
  "Region": "Central & Eastern Europe",
  "Link DE": "",
  "Link EN": "",
  "Link TR": "",
  "Lat": 47.8137521,
  "Long": 13.044259,
  "Image": "/Salzburg.jpg"
}];

// Store the matched hotels here
var matches = [];

// Loop over hotels 
for( i=0; i<locations.length; i++ ) {

    // Check if the location is in Austria, if so push it to our matches array
    if( locations[i].Country == 'Austria' ) {
        matches.push(locations[i]);
    }
}

// Check for matched hotels
console.log( matches );
```

Comment: Two things here that I believe is considered a bad practice.  First you are implicitly declaring "i" in the global namespace in your loop.  Second you are using "==" instead "===" to check the "Country" value.  Put a temp down vote for that after edit will reverse it.

Comment: I'm not going to edit my answer, it's a simple self-contained example so namespacing isn't an issue and using a strict === comparison is not considered a best practice for comparing two strings. I'd suggest reading https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/up%20&%20going/ch2.md#equality which dicates that as long as either value is not expected to be false, "" or an empty array then using == is "Not only safe, but in many cases it simplifies your code in a way that improves readability".

Comment: I have read that before but "===" says a lot more than "=="  in that you are expecting type and value equality which is even more important once this code is applied outside of this limited scope.  There are a whole world of bugs around "==" and "!=" when misused in an application of any realistic size.  I guess we will have to agree to disagree

Comment: I appreciate your position but I think when you consider that this person doesn't even know how to loop over an array of objects the chance of this needing to be used in an actual application is slim to none. Once they're in a situation where they need to worry about polluting namespaces and performing strict comparisons then sure, until then the simpler approach works just fine and makes it easier to understand.

Comment: I get it but my opinion is that "=="/"!=" is less readable because you have to consider all the possible implicit type conversions.  I get that this is a basic question but I think that it would be more important for a developer that is just starting out to start with the stricter equality.  While I disagree with that article hopefully we can agree that the philosophy promoted there really should only be applied by more advanced/knowledgeable javascript developers